# Order of execution in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have the following code in a website:

```
              alert('step 1');
              // save token if app user: 
              if (tokenViaApp !== '' ) {
                  alert('step 2')
                  $.ajax({ 
                      type: "GET", 
                      url: "/includes/notifications/", 
                      data: {
                          t: tokenViaApp    
                      }, 
                      success: function(msg) {  
                           localStorage.token_origin = 'app';
                           alert('step 3')
                      }
                    });
              }
              alert('step 4')
```

If the `if()` passes, then i would think the alert should be in this order:

```
step 1
step 2
step 3
step 4
```

but instead I get:

```
step 1
step 2
step 4
step 3
```

Why is this the case? and how can this be changed to process correctly?

Comment: It is processing correctly.  `$.ajax` is asynchronous

Comment: So, more importantly, *what is the problem?*

Comment: You probably want to wait for the ajax request to end and then go on with step 4. Call a function from the success handler of the ajax request.

Comment: The title of the above duplicate doesn't appear to be a match, but it's an all-encompassing question/answer which will give you a good ground on the *asynchronous* part of *a*jax.

Comment: alert 1, ok, alert 2, ok, ajax - ok, I'll fire this ajax off and get the result when it's ready/later, alert 4 - wait a bit - now I've got the ajax result back - alert 3.   Does what it says on the tin.

Comment: Thank you. the continued processing of the scripts on the page does not depend on the answer from the `ajax` call. but - i do not want the page to redirect before the `ajax` call has run (and there is a possible redirection further down in the script). Could this happen in theory (redirection before ajax call/complete) with the code above?

Comment: Yes, the code after the ajax fires will continue to run - so if you redirect, it will redirect before the result is back.  The server-side request itself will continue to run, it'll just never hit your success callback.  You can get around this by putting your redirect in `.done()` (or the older `success:`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ajax process asynchronously which means that other synchronous functions will run while the ajax request is still processing.

If you wish the order to be correct you will need to perform step 4 inside of the call back of your ajax function.

An alternative to this could be [async / await](https://javascript.info/async-await)

This way you can do

```js
const yourApiCall = () => {
    Promise.resolve(alert('step 3'))
  }
    
  const yourMainFunction = async () => {
    alert('step 1')
    alert ('step 2')
    await yourApiCall()
    alert('step 4')
  }

  yourMainFunction()
```

[This link](https://rowanmanning.com/posts/javascript-for-beginners-async/) might help regarding the differences between async and sync

Comment: Same syntax for jQuery?  as in, use of `const`, `await Promise.resolve` etc...?

Comment: You will probably need to use babel to use async await if you want to support old browsers https://jsfiddle.net/d19ckomt/1/

Comment: What would the syntax be if I am passing a parameter to the function? this does not work: `function saveTokenToUser(token) = async () => {`

Comment: Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/sdte3mwq/1/